# Android onscreen notification LED

Tags: android, android-notifications

As you may know, some newest Android phones lost the notification LED, my phone lost it too. So I am trying to make an app that turn on a few pixels on the AMOLED display after the phone is locked and screen is off. I searched about using screen saver to do it, but screensaver prevents the phone from locking, which isn't too ideal.

Any idea how to show things (turn on a few pixels) after phone is locked and screen off ?